# AES-128. Do there exist two different keys for a pair (text, encrypted text)?

Tags: encryption, aes

I have two very close questions.

### Question 1

`y = AES-128(x, key)`.
Is it possible that AES-128 will return the same y (encrypted text) for different keys?

I know that each key selects one permutation from the set of (2^128)! possible permutations. We have (2^128) possible keys and it is less than number of possible permutations. But it doesn't mean that there are no two different keys for some pair of text and encrypted text.

### Question 2

If we have fixed **x**,**y** (both of them have the size of 128 bit) does there exist a **key**( key size is 128 bit) so that 
`y = AES-128(x, key)` ?

Example.
We have 2 bit message and 2 bit key. There are 4 possible messages: msg1 = {0,0}, msg2={0,1}, msg3 = {1,0}, msg4 = {1,1} and there are 4 possible keys. We have 4! = 24 possible permutations of messages.
I can select the next permutations

```
| From\key | key1 | key2 | key3
--------------------------------
| msg1     | msg2 | msg3 | msg4
--------------------------------
| msg2     | msg1 | msg4 | msg3
--------------------------------
| msg3     | msg4 | msg1 | msg2
--------------------------------
| msg4     | msg3 | msg2 | msg1
--------------------------------
```

Here I have a mapping from a message to every message. e.g. I can get msg4 from msg1 using key3. Has the AES-128 the same property for the mentioned **x**,**y**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\newcommand{\given}{\mathrel{|}}$**Answer 1.**

Let $\pi_0, \pi_1$ be independent uniform random permutations of $\{0,1\}^{128}$.  What is the probability that for any fixed string $x \in \{0,1\}^{128}$, $\pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)$?

For any fixed string $x$ and each $i$, the variable $\pi_i(x)$ is a uniform random element of $\{0,1\}^{128}$.  (Only if we consider multiple distinct inputs $x_0 \ne x_1$ does the fact that $\pi_i$ is a uniform random *permutation* rather than a uniform random *function* come into play, when we consider whether repeated elements are possible in $\pi_i(x_0), \pi_i(x_1)$.)  Since $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ are independent, so are $\pi_0(x)$ and $\pi_1(x)$.

Thus
\begin{align*}
  \Pr[\pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)]
    &= \sum_y \Pr[\pi_0(x) = y \given \pi_1(x) = y]\cdot\Pr[\pi_1(x) = y] \\
    &= \sum_y \Pr[\pi_0(x) = y]\cdot\Pr[\pi_1(x) = y] \\
    &= \sum_y 2^{-128} \cdot 2^{-128}
     = 2^{128} \cdot 2^{-128} \cdot 2^{-128}
     = 2^{-128}.
\end{align*}

What if instead of uniform random $\pi_i$ we had $\pi_i = \operatorname{AES}_{k_i}$ for uniform random strings $k_i$?  If you could predict how that would affect the distribution nonnegligibly, you could distinguish AES from a uniform random permutation, violating the pseudorandom permutation family property that it is conjectured to exhibit, and there would be lots of cryptographers who would like to have a word with you.

So, for any fixed plaintext $x$, does there exist a pair of keys $k_0, k_1$ under which $\operatorname{AES}_{k_0}(x) = \operatorname{AES}_{k_1}(x)$?  Maybe, but you're not likely to find them—for each plaintext, only $1/2^{128}$ of the $2^{256}$ possible pairs $(k_0, k_1)$ of these keys is likely to work!  (It's not guaranteed that *any* of them will work, but it would be a remarkable publication if you could say one way or another about that guarantee.)

Does there exist *any* plaintext $x$ such that there exists a pair of keys $k_0, k_1$ under which $\operatorname{AES}_{k_0}(x) = \operatorname{AES}_{k_1}(x)$?  Note the order of quantifiers: We are not asking about some particular fixed $x$; we are asking whether there is *any* pair of keys that agrees on *any* plaintext.  This is a little trickier.  To approximate an answer, let's first try the uniform random *function* model.  A random function is not restricted to be a permutation, so its values at two distinct points are independent, which makes the analysis a little easier.

In the uniform random function model, what is the probability that there exists a plaintext $x$ on which two random functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ agree, $\Pr[\exists x. f_0(x) = f_1(x)]$?  We can answer this by answering it in the complement: what is the probability that for *all* plaintexts $x$, two random functions disagree on $x$?

\begin{align*}
  \Pr&[\exists x. f_0(x) = f_1(x)] \\
   &= 1 - \Pr[\neg\exists x. f_0(x) = f_1(x)] \\
   &= 1 - \Pr[\forall x. f_0(x) \ne f_1(x)] \\
   &= 1 - \prod_x \Pr[f_0(x) \ne f_1(x)] \\
   &= 1 - \prod_x \bigl(1 - \Pr[f_0(x) = f_1(x)]\bigr) \\
   &= 1 - \prod_x (1 - 1/2^{128})
    = 1 - (1 - 1/2^{128})^{2^{128}}.
\end{align*}

That may look painful to evaluate, but it's turns out to be approximately $1 - e^{-1} \approx 63\%$, since $(1 + x/n)^n \to e^x$ as $n \to \infty$.  (This is why you should pay attention in calculus, kids!)

That's the probability that there exists an input on which two uniform random *functions* agree.  Of course, AES isn't even conjectured to be a random function—it's designed to be a random permutation.  How does this answer change if we use random permutations $\pi_i$ instead of random functions $f_i$?  The crux is that $\pi_i(x)$ and $\pi_i(\xi)$ for $x \ne \xi$ are dependent—they cannot be equal—whereas $f_i(x)$ and $f_i(\xi)$ are independent.

So let's consider how that affects the expansion of $\Pr[\forall x. \pi_0(x) \ne \pi_1(x)]$, first by examining the case of two distinct inputs $x \ne \xi$, and expanding with the chain rule:

\begin{align*}
  \Pr&[\pi_0(x) \ne \pi_1(x), \pi_0(\xi) \ne \pi_1(\xi)] \\
   &= \Pr[\pi_0(x) \ne \pi_1(x) \given \pi_0(\xi) \ne \pi_1(\xi)]
      \cdot \Pr[\pi_0(\xi) \ne \pi_1(\xi)].
\end{align*}

For the case of $f_i$, by independence of $f_i(x)$ and $f_i(\xi)$ we reduced this to

\begin{align*}
  \Pr[f_0(x) \ne f_1(x)] \cdot \Pr[f_0(\xi) \ne f_1(\xi)]
  = (1 - 2^{-128}) \cdot (1 - 2^{-128}).
\end{align*}

How do the left-hand factors compare?  We can expand the permutation case by Bayes' rule:

\begin{align*}
  \Pr&[\pi_0(x) \ne \pi_1(x) \given \pi_0(\xi) \ne \pi_1(\xi)] \\
   &= 1 - \Pr[\pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x) \given \pi_0(\xi) \ne \pi_1(\xi)] \\
   &= 1 - \Pr[\pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)]
        \frac{\Pr[\pi_0(\xi) \ne \pi_1(\xi) \given \pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)]}
             {\Pr[\pi_0(\xi) \ne \pi_1(\xi)]} \\
   &= 1 - \Pr[\pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)]
        \frac{1 - \Pr[\pi_0(\xi) = \pi_1(\xi) \given \pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)]}
             {1 - \Pr[\pi_0(\xi) = \pi_1(\xi)]} \\
   &= 1 - 2^{-128} \frac{1 - 1/(2^{128} - 1)}{1 - 1/2^{128}}.
\end{align*}

The quantity $1/(2^{128} - 1)$ arises because if $\pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)$, the common value is *excluded* from the possible values of $\pi_0(\xi)$ and $\pi_1(\xi)$.

Thus, $$\Pr[\pi_0(x) \ne \pi_1(x) \given \pi_0(\xi) \ne \pi_1(\xi)] > \Pr[f_0(x) \ne f_1(x)],$$ from which we can conclude that $$\Pr[\forall x. \pi_0(x) \ne \pi_1(x)] > \Pr[\forall x. f_0(x) \ne f_1(x)].$$ This further means that $$\Pr[\exists x. \pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)] < \Pr[\exists x. f_0(x) = f_1(x)],$$ so there's less than about a 63% chance that *any* pair of permutations chosen uniformly at random agree on any plaintext.

Turning back to AES, we might guess that for about 63% of the key pairs $(k_0, k_1)$ there is a plaintext $x$ with $\operatorname{AES}_{k_0}(x) = \operatorname{AES}_{k_1}(x)$.  Not bad odds for *existence*—but will you find them by flailing around randomly, which is about the only thing you can do until you're ready to publish a novel cryptanalysis of AES?  No—there's too much hay in that stack of $2^{128}$ possible plaintexts.

**Answer 2.**

Exercise for the reader.  If you followed Answer 1, you should have all the tools you need to answer this yourself.

Comment: Why do you have the same probability(e^-1) for not getting matching pairs(the quote is " the probability that for every single one you **get no** matching pairs ") and for a random triple in the space with dimension 2^384 that you **do have** mentioned property(the quote is "that π0(x)=π1(x)"?

Comment: I might have made the equivalent of a sign error in direct probability space.

Comment: No, I might have done something _horribly_ wrong toward the end, because _obviously_ there's no way the probability of any triple $(\pi_0, \pi_1, x)$ having $\pi_0(x) = \pi_1(x)$ is anywhere near $e^{-1}$.  I must have meant something like the probability for any $x$ that there _exists_ such a pair $(\pi_0, \pi_1)$ satisfying that.  Pooh.

Comment: This squeamish ossifrage is embarrassed by how wrong its analysis was and hopes that it looks better now.

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure there's at least one sign error (in log-odds space, anyway) in there now.