# Is it possible to get partial plaintext when using the wrong key with AES-256

Tags: aes

I have a scheme where a key and a data blob are provided that I need to decrypt. I do not know if the key provided is correct and I want to throw an error in my system if the wrong key is used.

I get no other information other than the key and the blob, so I want to put a magic string (8 bytes) at the beginning of the blob so I know that the correct key was used.

**Is it possible for the magic string to be decrypted correctly when using the wrong key?**

This seems like it shouldn't be possible as it is a partial plaintext result from using the wrong key, but I can't find a source that confirms or denies if this is possible.

Comment: Well, I'm lazy to write the true probability ( we had such Q/A) that the probability of different ciphertext results in the same plaintext under the same key. Yes possible. Why don't you use HMAC of the plaintext than encrypt?

Comment: This is the reverse of it for AES-128 [AES-128. Do there exist two different keys for a pair (text, encrypted text)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52857/18298). Just change the enc to dec and 128 to 256, done.